# Can Server-side Blazor App run .Net Core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard-2.0, blazor

Building out an MVP in Server-Side Blazor and I noticed that the Blazor.App project uses Net Standard 2.0, and of course all of my projects for the backend are .Net Core 2.1.

It seems to me that since the Blazor.App is running completely on the server, and since .Net Core 2.1 is a superset of .Net Standard, that there shouldn't be any problem changing Blazor.App to Net Core 2.1.

Is there any risk in doing this? Should I just change all my other projects to .Net Standard 2.0 and deal with any incompatibilities that might exist there?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can, but you must take into account that this change may prevent the existing possibilty of switching to Blazor running on the client...